# Find the number of ways of picking the following cards from a standard, 52-card deck.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

a) a king and a queen
b) a king or queen
c) king and a red card
d) king or a red card

For a), I can see that, since there are 4 kings and 4 queens in a deck, the number of ways of picking both would be $(4)(4) = 16$. This is the multiplication rule? Why does this work, and how would I know to use it?

For b), I can see that the ways of picking a king OR a queen is, instead of multiplying, I must add $4+4=8$ ways. Addition rule? When does this work, and how do I know to use it?

c) and d) are where things start to get even fuzzier for me. How would I go about starting these?

I'm thinking that if a) is similar to c), then couldn't I use the multiplication rule? As in, 4 kings times 26 total red cards? But this produces an incorrect answer. Next, I thought that maybe I should exclude the kings from the set of red cards, but 4 times 22 is still incorrect.

Comment: Only two of the kings are red: diamond king, heart king. (The other kings: one club, one spade) are black. But you need to determine whether picking only a red king counts as picking "a king and a red card"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can use the multiplication rule in the first one is that you are computing the number of ways to take one item each from two sets which are disjoint. There may be a more elegant way of explaining this, but I am still an amateur. :)

Presumably, by "a king and a red card" they mean "two cards, one of which is a king, and the other of which is a red card." E.g. a single red king would not suffice. If this is the case, you must take $2(26)$, which is 2 for the black kings and 26 for the red cards (same rule as before). Now you start counting the cases involving sets that are not disjoint. Take the king of diamonds...there are 25 red cards you can pair with it. Now take the king of hearts. Again there are 25 red cards you can pair with it, but one of the possibilities (drawing the two red kings) was already considered. So the answer should be $$2(26) + 1(25) + 1(24).$$ In part d, you just have to take the number of elements in the set $\{\text{King or red card}\}$, which is 28.

Edit: I fixed an error, but then my correction was wrong, so I changed it back!

Comment: When I add that, I arrive at 101, but the answer is 102.

Comment: Hmm... perhaps I made a mistake. Let me see.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know where my mistake is. Perhaps someone else can find it.

Comment: @EricAuld Your rule for the king of hearts should be the same as your rule for the king of diamonds. These are mutually exclusive. _Either_ you pick the king of hearts and then another red card (having already chosen 1 red card) _or_ you pick the kind of diamonds and then another red card (having already chosen 1 red card).

Comment: Oh, of course. We are considering order here, so those are distinct possibilities.

Comment: @EricAuld So, out of 26 total red cards, there are two(black kings) which count for selection, but are not red. (2)(26). Then, for the next event, we still have 2 kings which are not red, but once you have chosen a card, there is one less red card in the total set to choose from, so that is why it becomes (2)(25). Is that the gist of it?

Comment: Your answer before the edit was correct; the solution in the OP's book is in error. Without regard to order of selection: there are $2\cdot26$ ways to select a black king and a red card. There are $2\cdot 24$ ways to select *exactly one* red king and another red card, and there is one way to select two red kings.

Comment: @DavidMitra (2)(26) + (25) + (24)? That's the correct answer?

Comment: @DavidMitra I thought so! After I went AFK, I realized order was not the issue.